# what is difference between isa-simulator and c++ simulator in riscv?

Tags: riscv

I'm starting to go into RISC-V.

While I'm diving into the source code repository,

I found that there exist many simulation environments.

But What I'm confusing is that why there exist ISA-simulator that derives from riscv-tool and C++ simulator which comes from chisel3 RTL in the rocket repository.

What is the difference between these simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ based cycle accurate simulator is for a specific RISCV 
implementation. It does model how many 
cycles the processor takes for each instruction in each situation. As it 
simulates the hardware in more detail, it is expected to be slower than 
Spike. Like Spike (but unlike the Verilog model), you can just compile 
the C++ model with a normal compiler and run it as ordinary software, no 
expensive simulation tools are required.

An instruction set simulator (ISS) is a simulation model, usually coded in a high-level programming language, which mimics the behavior of a mainframe or microprocessor by "reading" instructions and maintaining internal variables which represent the processor's registers.